# Procedurally weight a mesh based on the face angles of an animated mesh

Tags: mesh

I would like to procedurally emit particles (fluid mode) from the 'steepest' parts of animated 'waves' created by a Ocean modifier to attempt to emulate foam and splashes. I assume frame by frame normals values could be used, but cant figure out how.

So how would I go about procedurally weighting a mesh based on the face angles of an animated mesh? *(ocean modifier in displace mode)*.

Answer (score 4):

While this isn't *impossible* to do with blender at the moment, but its not something you can do easily, and doing this via a script would be very slow.

It would involve 2x modifier stack calculations per frame change.

- Add a frame-change-post handler.
- this handler must update the scene - `scene.update()` so the data it deals with is valid before you start to operate on it.
- get the final calculated mesh and inspect its normals.
- modify the original meshes vertex groups how you like.
- throw away the copy of the mesh, only generated to inspect normals.
- tag the mesh to be updated `mesh.update_tag()`
- and run `scene.update()` again.

So officially this kind of thing isnt supported, and what I have suggested is very much a hack. Ideally modifier plugins would much more easily allow this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful reply. I will take a look at a scripted soultion. Cheers